# Text Editor Unable to delete last new line character

Tags: linux

I am using Geany, to edit a simple file on ubuntu. There is a strange error. When i delete the last '\n' character, when I save it is still there. I do not want a newline line character because I am using matlab to parse the file, and it counts the '\n' character as 1 character.
Any help to remove it from the file? Why does my text editor not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#saving-files) there is an "Ensure newline at file end" option when saving (under Preferences -> Files), try disabling that.

As a related story (and if anyone should come by this through googling), I had the same problem with [Nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.1.html) not long ago - turns out you need to start it with the `-L` switch to make it not insert newlines at the end.